# How to Find the Next Date in BigQuery: Prioritize TableA's Maximum Date or TableB's Minimum Date if Missing in TableA

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working on a BigQuery query where I need to select a start date based on specific conditions. I have two tables, `mydb.processed_data` and `mydb.raw_data`, and I want to set the `start_date` variable in the following manner:

If the maximum date (`MAX(EVENT_DATE)`) exists in `mydb.processed_data`, I want to use that maximum date as the `start_date`.
If there is no maximum date in `mydb.processed_data`, I want to use the minimum date (`MIN(EVENT_DATE)`) from `mydb.raw_data` as the `start_date`.
I've attempted to achieve this with the following code:

```
DECLARE start_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE();

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT MAX(EVENT_DATE) FROM `mydb.processed_data`
  )
  THEN start_date = SELECT MAX(EVENT_DATE) FROM mydb.processed_data`

ELSE
  start_date = SELECT MIN(EVENT_DATE) FROM `mydb.raw_data`
END IF;

SELECT *
FROM `mydb.raw_data`
WHERE
  DATE(DATE_TRUNC(EVENT_DATE, DAY)) = DATE(DATE_TRUNC(start_date, DAY))
  AND DATE(DATE_TRUNC(EVENT_DATE, DAY)) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

However, I'm encountering issues with my code, and I'm not sure if I'm using the correct syntax for dynamic date selection. Can someone help me identify the problem and provide a solution or alternative approach to achieve this dynamic date selection in BigQuery?

Comment: It's odd that your `where` conditions are doing an equality comparison to the `start_date` _and_ the `current_date()`. I would assume you probably want to find `event_date`s where it is >/>= `start_date` and </<= 'current_date()`.

Comment: Having said that, it would be good to know the actual problem you are having. Is there an error message? If so, what is it? If not, what is your expected versus actual  output for some sample data?

Comment: @EdmCoff because I want to return records for start_date being one day at a time for each time the query is ran, but never pulling data from the same day as today. The error I keep getting is Syntax error: Expected END IF

Comment: "but never pulling data from the same day as today" -> Then why are you checking that event_date = current_date()? It looks like you are _only_ pulling data from today.

Comment: There are several syntax error in your statement like an odd number of backticks, missing `set` keyword, missing semicolons. But do you really need the `if then else`? Could you just replace `start_date` in your main query with something like `COALESCE( (SELECT MAX(EVENT_DATE) FROM mydb.processed_data), (SELECT MIN(EVENT_DATE) FROM mydb.raw_data) )`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `processed_data` table exists before selecting a record.

Simple query the tables in your dataset and check if the table exists, ensuring you've run the query at least once and the results were saved to a table.

Then using the `SET` command, update the `DECLARED` variable with the results of one table or the other depending on the results of the table check.

```
DECLARE start_date DATE;
-- Check if mydb.processed_data exists
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project_name.data_set.__TABLES__` WHERE table_id = 'processed_data') > 0 THEN
  SET start_date = (SELECT MAX(DATE(EVENT_DATE)) FROM `project_name.data_set.processed_data`);
ELSE
  SET start_date = (SELECT MIN(DATE(EVENT_DATE)) FROM `project_name.data_set.raw_data`);
END IF;

SELECT start_date;
```

You can then use `start_date` in the following query however you need.